# c++ overload ostream doesn't work for default construct with empty argument

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Here is an example taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
    int mo, da, yr;
public:
    Date()
    {
        mo = 10; da = 10; yr = 99;
    }
    Date(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        mo = m; da = d; yr = y;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Date dt0();
    cout << dt0 << endl;

    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    cout << dt;
}
```

I'd expect the output to be

```
10/10/99
5/6/92
```

But what I get was

```
1
5/6/92
```

What or how can I work this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to C++, where you can get tripped up because of the [most vexing parse!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

`dt0` is *not* an object, it is a function! When you output it, you are actually outputting the address of the function `dt0`, which always evaluates to true, i.e. `1`.

You can replace the `()` with `{}`, so not ambiguity occurs:

```
Date dt0{};
```

Or just drop the parenthesis altogether:

```
Date dt0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Best answer in a few mins!

Comment: Just so you know, that `cout << &dt0 << endl` will print the same output, because both indicate the address of the function. (And in that explicit way, it could reduce some compiler warnings, if you really mean it.)

Comment: @Dean I already knew that, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm sure you do. That comment was actually for the OP. :)

Comment: @Dean Oh, then you should have mentioned him with @, OP might never see it :)